# how to get the list of all table of a key space in cassandra

Tags: c#, database, cassandra, datastax, cqlsh

I am new to cassandra, I am currently using CassandraCSharpDriver in a dummy application. I want to get the list of all the tables a user has described in a given key space.

```
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints("IPAddress").Build();
        Session session = cluster.Connect("MyKeySpace");
```

In this code I want to get the list of all the tables of MyKeySpace

Comment: I am not sure, the solution mentioned in the "How to check if a Cassandra table exists" is not working out for me... or may be I am not using it properly..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll run through how I would prepare that list of tables with the DataStax Cassandra C# driver:

Connect to your cluster:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints("IPAddress").Build();
Session session = cluster.Connect();
```

I'll create a `List<String>` and use a prepared statement (because that's just a good idea) to bind the name of your keyspace.  My CQL statement is only selecting `columnfamily_name`, which should be what you need.

```
List<String> tableList = new List<String>();

String strCQL = "SELECT columnfamily_name "
    + "FROM system.schema_columnfamilies WHERE keyspace_name=? ";
PreparedStatement pStatement = _session.Prepare(strCQL);
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(pStatement);
boundStatement.Bind("MyKeySpace");
```

Now I'll execute the statement, iterate through the results, and add each table name to the List I created above.

```
RowSet results = session.Execute(boundStatement);

foreach (Row result in results.GetRows())
{
    tableName = result.GetValue<String>("columnfamily_name");
    tableList.Add(tableName);
}
```

Now you should have a list of tables that you can add to your UI.

Comment: I know I probably provided a little too much hand-holding on this one, but I was just happy to get a question from somebody who was actually using a recent, supported driver.

Answer (score 5):

You can run:

```
select * from system.schema_columnfamilies where keyspace_name='MyKeySpace';
```

It runs against the "system" keyspace.

Comment: I am sorry, if I haven't conveyed my message properly, Actually I have created 3 table in "MyKeySpace", I want to select one of them through UI at run time to run my queries. to display in my UI, I want the list   of all the tables in "MyKeySpace"

Comment: The query will return you precisely that. The columnfamily_name field of the response will contain the table name.

Comment: @ashic +1 for the correct query.  It's not your fault that the OP doesn't know what to do with the result.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get **column names**:

   ```
   SELECT column_name FROM system.schema_columns WHERE keyspace_name = 'KeySpaceName' AND columnfamily_name = 'TableName';
   ```
2. Get **column family names**, i.e., table names:

   ```
   select columnfamily_name from system.schema_columnfamilies where keyspace_name='KeySpaceName';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is the option to use cluster metadata as well to get a string listing of keyspaces like so

```
var cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints("IPAddress").Build();
var keyspaces = cluster.Metadata.GetKeyspaces();
foreach (var keyspaceName in keyspaces)
{
   Console.WriteLine(keyspaceName);
}
```